# MySQL - Should I create a different database for users

Tags: mysql

My question isn't really MySQL related, but that's the database I am using. My project was small so I put my user data and my business stuff on the same database. However, it's grown so much since and I've been thinking of separating the user part into an other database. It was nice to have them on the same database since I could do JOIN operations whenever I need to query things. I don't think I can do that on different databases. Are there any other downsides with 2 databases for the same web app? Would connection between them be an issue if they don't live in the same data center, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more verbose to `JOIN` between tables that are in different databases; no performance hit.  Example:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM db1.table_a AS a
    JOIN db2.table_b AS b  ON a.foo = b.bar
    ...
```

That is, having all tables in a single database versus multiple databases should be a user decision without concern for what the engine needs to do.

Use a single connection on a single server.  (Multiple connections cannot `JOIN`.)  For exceptions:  see `FEDERATEDx` and `Spider`.  But this does not seem relevant to your situation.